# How to pass value from a selected cell in embedded collectionView to another viewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

In `UIViewController 1`, I have set up an array. This `UIViewController` segues to `UIViewController 2`.

In `UIViewController 2`, there is a `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCell`. There's also a `UIButton` which segues perfectly fine back to `UIViewController 1`.

In the custom cell, there is a `collectionView`. This is populated by the array from `ViewController 1`.

My question is, when an item is selected in the `collectionView` (`UIViewController 2` - custom `UITableViewCell` class), how to pass that value all the way back to `UIViewController 1`?

I'm sorry if this is repetitive. I've referred to many similar entries here but nothing seems to be working. I've also tried this:

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-collection-view-tutorial/

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipePhoto"]) {
    NSArray *indexPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];
    RecipeViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [indexPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    destViewController.recipeImageName = [recipeImages[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
  }
}
```

I keep getting the null value returned and I'm not sure why.

(I'm not using storyboard. And this is my first attempt at programming of any kind. Would appreciate any input!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UICollectionViewDelegate`.

Add in your class:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate { ... }
```

and use `- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` this event is called when the cell is selected; you must save the value in a property; like that:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   selectedRecipeImageName = [recipeImages[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
... 
   [self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```

and then:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipePhoto"]) {
    RecipeViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.recipeImageName = selectedRecipeImageName
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. So simple yet I couldn't wrap my head around it at the time. By the way, sorry for the delayed reply. I'm doing this on the side.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either with delegation or completion block.

To solve with delegation please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343519/pass-data-back-to-previous-viewcontroller).

To solve with completion block please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397762/using-blocks-to-pass-data-back-to-view-controller).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please avoid link-only as answers. You can use the "flag" button to flag as a duplicate if you think this has been answered already.